# Joining on one column and if no match join on another

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I am attempting to use multiple columns in my join like this:

```
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table2 s ON t.number = s.number OR t.letter = s.letter
```

Both of these tables have several hundred thousand rows of data and it is running infinitely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your title says you want to try `JOIN`ing on one column and if there isn't a match, to `JOIN` on a different column, but your question says you want to use both columns in a single join condition.  Which of the two are you trying to do?

Comment: Are the tables suitably indexed? Are the index statistics up to date?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I am trying to do what the title says join on one column and if there isn't a match look to another to match on.  I am attempting to do so with the example above which may not be the most effective way to do so.

Answer (score 15):

You mean something like:

```
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table2 s ON case
  when t.number = s.number then 1
  when t.letter = s.letter then 1
  else 0 end = 1
```

The first matching condition wins.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to use `left join` and fix the rest of the query:

```
FROM Table1 t LEFT JOIN
     Table2 sn
     ON t.number = sn.number LEFT JOIN
     Table2 sl
     ON t.letter = sl.letter and sn.number is null
```

For performance, you want indexes on `Table2(number)` and `Table2(letter)`.

Answer (score 4):

ORs are usually produce bad performance. I would go for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
       INNER JOIN Table2 s ON t.number = s.number 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
     INNER JOIN Table2 s ON t.letter = s.letter
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the OR keyword between your ON conditions works well for me, and it's easier to understand for developers:

```html
SELECT * FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
ON
(table1.column_to_join = table2.column
OR
table1.other_column_to_join = table2.column
```